# Printing hardware information to a printer with color

Tags: linux, linux-mint, printing, inxi

So at my job I test laptops for functionality with a linux mint live usb. I've been looking for a way to get the hardware information and print it out. So far I have it about how I want it by using inxi -M -C -B -m > output.txt. I then print it out with lpr.

What I would like is some of the words to be color or bold when printed out. Specifically the words before the information like CPU: or Memory:. Basically just like it does in terminal.

I've researched quite a bit and have not found a way to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible with a .txt.

Comment: Ok, but what about other formats? I've gotten color text in html however when I print it out there is no color, just the code around the word that showed it as color.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted to do.

1. Used aha to convert the inxi output to an html file so i was able to retain color text.
2. Used sed to remove an unwanted text.
3. used wkhtmltopdf to add header with title and date then convert it to pdf.
4. lpr the converted pdf and it came out perfect.

Though it did not retain the color, the text was bold which is good enough.

Comment: Very clever solution.